# MySql : How to select records based on current week?

Tags: mysql, dayofweek

How can i select record in a days range based on the current week, example : I want to select all records in rage on current Sunday to Saturday

This below works very well but only for a Monday to Sunday week and I want to do the same for Sunday to Saturday week

```
WHERE  YEARWEEK(`date`, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1)
```

Comment: it seams it's just as simple as using 0 as mode (second param) when in look into the manual..

Comment: Still struggling? See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_yearweek.asp you should use:

```
WHERE  YEARWEEK(`date`, 0) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 0)
```